# Resultados errones en formulas

Tags: python

Me pide hacer una funcion que calcule la distancia horizontal y la altura maxima de un movimiento parabolico.

```
import math

def YX (a,vi):
   t=(2*vi*math.sin(a))/9.8                                   #Calcular tiempo
   x=(vi*math.cos(a))*t                                       #Calcular distancia
   ymax=math.tan(a)-0.5*9.8*(x**2 /(vi**2 * math.cos(a*2)))   #Calcular altura maxima
   print("El valor de la distacia horizontal es " ,x," m")    
   print("El valor de la altuta maxima es de ", ymax, "m")

a=float(input("Ingrese el valor del angulo ", ))
vi=float(input("Ingrese el valor de la velocidad inicial "))
YX(a,vi)
```

Se supone que todas las formulas estan bien pero los resultados que me arroja son incoherentes, un ejemplo de esto es que la distancia horizontal es negativa, no se si es porque lee a como grados o como radianes.

Ejemplo,

```
Ingrese el valor del angulo 65
Ingrese el valor de la velocidad inicial 215.22
El valor de la distacia horizontal es  -4396.1408762651745  m
El valor de la altuta maxima es de  5564.78819850982 m
```

Los resultados deberian dar.

```
x=3600        #aproximadamente
ymax=1900     #aproximadamente
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomendaría leer la documentación de [`math`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html) antes de usar las funciones. Parece que tu idea inicial era la correcta, leyendo las partes de sin, cos y tan, te pide el número en rads. y es algo tan simple como solo convertir `a` a radianes:

```
def YX (a,vi):
    a = a * math.pi / 180
# ...resto del código
```

(Alternativamente, puedes ponerle `a = math.radians(a)`)

Esto te devuelve:

```
Ingrese el valor del angulo 65
Ingrese el valor de la velocidad inicial 215.22
El valor de la distacia horizontal es  3620.705026943353  m
El valor de la altuta maxima es de  2159.638618712338 m
```